# Ошибка RandomRangeInt is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead

Tags: c#, unity3d

помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку

> "UnityException: RandomRangeInt is not allowed to be called from a
> MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in
> Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'Spawner' on game
> object 'Spawns'. See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual
> for further details. UnityEngine.Random.Range (System.Int32 min,
> System.Int32 max) (at
> C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Random.bindings.cs:48)
> Spawner..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Spawner.cs:14)"

Я делал спавны рандомных объектов в определённых местах, для этого использовал рандомные числа(вроде с этим связана ошибка).

Comment: Ошибка вам говорит о том, что нужно делать это в методах `Awake` или `Start`, а не в конструкторе класса.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/ `RandomRangeInt нельзя вызывать из конструктора MonoBehaviour (или инициализатора поля экземпляра), вместо этого вызовите его в Awake или Start.`

Comment: Когда я поместил рандомные числа в Start или Awake, то они получаются локальными и в Update я не могу их использовать @CrazyElf

Comment: @Jordan_Milka Нет, смотрите, *область видимости переменной* и *место инициализации переменной* - это две большие разницы. Оставьте *описание типа переменной* там, где оно у вас было. Но инициализируйте эту переменную с помощью `RandomRangeInt` в `Start` или в `Awake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MonoBehaviour` - это особый вид класса в Юнити. И у них (ЕМНИП) нет конструктора. Вся предварительная инициализцая и настройка должна производиться в методах `Awake` или `Start`. Эти методы как раз вызываются

Функция `Awake` вызывается когда экземпляр скрипта будет загружен.

Функция `Start` вызывается до обновления первого кадра(first frame) только если скрипт включен.

Comment: Конструктор есть, его даже вызвать можно, и переопределить тоже, но это никто не делает и не советуют делать.